# GitHub API commit file raw_url 404

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using the GitHub API and I'm getting a 404 on the `raw_url` for a commit file entry that actually refers to a "subproject".  For example the **libgit2** entry at the bottom of [this](https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commits/39c2ed2233b3d99e33c031183e26996d1210c329) commit has the following `raw_url`: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/raw/39c2ed2233b3d99e33c031183e26996d1210c329/libgit2

Here's the commit on GitHub.com: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/39c2ed2233b3d99e33c031183e26996d1210c329#L19L1

Is there any way to detect that a file is in fact a subproject using the GitHub API?